# Given three points in the Cartesian plane, what are the coordinates of the Fermat point?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given three points $P(x_1,y_1),P(x_2,y_2) \text{ and } P(x_3,y_3)$ in the Cartesian plane, what are the coordinates of the Fermat point?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point

Comment: It is well defined - find the third vertices for two of the triangles and than just calculate the intersection of the lines created with the proper vertices - what is your challenge?

Comment: This is an algorithm, not a formula.

Comment: http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X13